# More call for bot Radio music in Jamendo

Tags: php, api, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm making a bot telegram to hear the Jamendo Radio by their API.
I wrote this:

```
        $url_radio = 'https://api.jamendo.com/v3.0/radios/stream/?client_id='.CLIENT_ID_J.'&format=jsonpretty&name='.$id;
        $result = file_get_contents($url_radio);
        $update = json_decode($result, true);
        $res = $update['results'];

        $sendto =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($res[0]['dispname']);
        file_get_contents($sendto);

        $sendto =API_URL."sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chatID."&photo=".urlencode($res[0]['playingnow']['track_image']);
        file_get_contents($sendto);

        $name = $res[0]['playingnow']['track_name'].' - '.$res[0]['playingnow']['artist_name'];

        $url_track = 'https://api.jamendo.com/v3.0/albums/tracks/?client_id='.CLIENT_ID_J.'&track_id='.$res[0]['playingnow']['track_id'];
        $result = file_get_contents($url_track);
        $update = json_decode($result, true);
        $res = $update['results'][0];

        $sendto =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($name.chr(10).$res["tracks"][0]['audio']);
        file_get_contents($sendto);
```

It works perfectly, but I would avoid too many calls by: "file_get_contents($sendto);".

is there any alternative way to avoid those 3 calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem clearly, you can avoid one query.

[SendPhoto API method](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) has caption param. You can use this field for showing    `$res[0]['dispname']`